# Forcing page to refresh after its content has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, refresh

I have a button which acts as an indicator, so has two states; pressing it toggles the state, and moves on to the next page.

Pressing the button calls a JavaScript function which handles this.

Having changed a button's 'src' image, using jQuery, I wish for the user to see the image change, pause for a fraction of a second, and only then see the next page displayed.

I am finding that the image does not visibly change until the JavaScript function returns, but this is after the pause, and after the page change. I.e. the browser does not show the page changes until the button's function has exit.

So I wish to cause the page to repaint in the browser, before the pause.
All the solutions I have tried refresh the page to its state on the server, and any changes I made to it in jQuery are lost.

Is there a way to force the page or button to be repainted, which will honor the changes I made to it in JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#YourButtonWhichTriggersChanges").click(function() {
    // page repaint code, image change, etc.

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
        // use window.location.href = "my/new/url.html";
        // or window.location.replace("my/new/url.html");  
        // to change the page instead of just reloading.
    }, 1000);
});
```

Where `1000` is the number of milliseconds you want to wait before refreshing the page.

---

Edit: I think you want this code instead:

```
$("#ApproveButton").css('backgroundImage', 'url(\'img/but/proof/ApprovePageButton.png\')');
```

The extra backslashes are in there to escape out the single quotes in the url parameter.

---

Another edit: Here's a combination of the two solutions I supplied which should work:

```
$("#ApproveButton").click(function() {
        // actually repaint the button's background image
        $(this).css('backgroundImage', 'url(\'img/but/proof/ApprovePageButton.png\')');

        // change the page after 1000 milliseconds have gone by.
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.reload();
            /* use window.location.href = "my/new/url.html";
             * or window.location.replace("my/new/url.html");  
             * to change the page instead of just reloading.
             */
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, Elliot, but unfortunately I still have the same problem -- the window.location.reload(); reverts the page to its original state before the changes I made to its elements, using jQuery. This may well be because refreshing the html calls a Javascript function to set up its original appearance. I think I need a way to cause just the button element to be repainted immediately, without the page being reloaded, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can I see the code you're using to change the button's image?

Comment: Certainly, it's
$("#ApproveButton").attr('src', "img/but/proof/ApprovePageButton.png");

Comment: Certainly, it's
$("#ApproveButton").attr('src', "img/but/proof/ApprovePageButton.png");
Basically we're lighting up a check mark in the button.
Nick

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Elliot. I'll try it tomorrow. Nick

Comment: Hi Elliot, I'm afraid that still did not work -- the results of the background image change only show up after the button click function has returned -- by which time the page view has already been changed by my script. That must be confusing to you -- the button I am playing with is one you click, it should briefly change so the button has a green check mark, then the page turns to the next page, so the green check mark turns black again (as this second page has not been approved yet). It's all working apart from the brief display of a green check mark does not occur.

Comment: Try a combination of the solutions I suggested then, see my edited answer once more.

Comment: Right, I've solved it. The answer was to do the 'page turn' in the setTimeout, this allowed the button click function to return, the window to update to show the check mark, and a short time after that the page turn occurs. Phew. Thanks again for your assistance, Elliot. -- Nick.

Comment: Yep, cool. Glad I could help. If this answer was of assistance to you, could you upvote and accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my reputation is not high enough (nor can I chat to tell you this!).

Comment: You can accept the answer regardless of your reputation, I believe.